# Entity Framework code first: How to set a one to one relationships not using the concept of "principal" and same id?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two classes. The first one is this:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birth { get; set; }
    public Sex Sex { get; set; }
    public List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public Picture ProfilePicture { get; set; }
}
```

And the second one is this:

```
public class Picture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Album Album { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Pictures are saved in a table, and a user can have as many pictures as he want inside albums and they are accessed using albums. Here's the `Album` class:

```
public class Album
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public AlbumType Type { get; set; }
    public List<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

Having a `Picture` object, I want to be able to retrieve the `User` owner of that picture, doing something like `picture.User`, that currently works. But only one of those pictures can be the profile picture. Because the profile picture is retrieved almost always, I would like to be able to do in code something like this:

```
LoadPicture(user.ProfilePicture.Id);
```

My problem is that EF thinks I want to create a one-to-one relationship in which I have to define a principal and both entities must have the same ID. `Picture`'s entities must have their own ID and `User`'s must have their own ID too. How can I say that to EF so `user.ProfilePicture.Id` works?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the database model can't be modified?

Comment: @GertArnold It can be modified. The idea is just to write in the user's record the id of his profile picture and, in code, to be able to get the picture object with a line of code like `user.ProfilePicture`. In other words, there should be a foreign key with the id of `Picture` in the users table instead of a foreign key with the id of `User` in the pictures table and to be able to write `user.ProfilePicture`. I don't know how to do it with code first. Maybe it can't be done. With just EF, maybe yes, but with code first, maybe no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Having a Picture object, I want to be able to retrieve the User owner of that picture, doing something like picture.User, that currently works.

I would suggest you either removing or renaming the `User` property since it's misleading - the owner of the picture is `Picture.Album.User`, while this property really represents the reverse of the `User.ProfilePicture`.

Also you really need (as exception states) to resolve the principal/dependent part of the `User.ProfilePicture` relationship using fluent API.

So, here are the options:

(A) remove the `Picture.User` property

```
public class Picture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Album Album { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

and use the following inside the your DbContext `OnModelCreating` override:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOptional(e => e.ProfilePicture)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal();
```

(B) Rename the `Picture.User` property

```
public class Picture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Album Album { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public User ProfileOf { get; set; }
}
```

and use

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOptional(e => e.ProfilePicture)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal(e => e.ProfileOf);
```

Both options will introduce `int?` column in the `Picture` table being FK to the `User` table.

Comment: I took into account the (A) suggestion, thanks for that, but I wanna keep a column of picture's id in the user table, to create a foreign key into the picture's table pointing to the user's one only to say which picture is the profile picture is something I would like to avoid. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Kuma only if `Picture`-`User` is 1:n. And it *is* 1:n, because there's nothing in the data model that prevents multiple users to refer to the same picture. You need to rule that out by some form of validation.

Comment: You can do that by changing the word `Principal` to `Dependent` in the configuration, but note that it would create dependency cycle, i.e. create user, create album, create picture, set picture as user's profile picture - EF cannot handle that in a single transaction.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks to the suggestion made by @IvanStoev I changed that. There isn't `Picture.User` property anymore.

Comment: I know it looks strange from the database design standpoint, but I would suggest you to keep it this way if you don't want to encounter later create/delete user issues.

Comment: @IvanStoev I just tried what you said and it works. But you are right, it creates a dependency cycle. I don't know if that's very bad, after all, an user will always create an account first and then he will upload a picture. So both things will never happen in a single transaction. I don't know if it would affect to other things, like delete in cascade or something. Anyway, thanks very much for your help.